# Junit: Use same test object in multiple test classes

Tags: java, junit

I have multiple, individual test classes which all use the same test object. At the moment I'm using @Before in each of these classes, which is obviously not a very good solution.

One option of course is to inherit from an abstract class which creates this object. As stated [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/unit-testing/3-reasons-why-we-should-not-use-inheritance-in-our-tests/), this is not a good idea as well.

Another option would be External Resource, but that is - as the name says - for resources rather than test objects.

I feel like I'm missing something since this must be a basic task in JUnit.

Comment: To be honest, I disagree with that article. DRY does not necessarily completely apply to test code. You want your tests to be self contained. You don't want them to rely on anything outside of themselves. That is the most important thing. If it means you're repeating yourself a lot, I'd suggest your classes are possibly not very well designed.

Comment: I have a REST controller which receives this object as a JSON, further I have a DAO class which persists this object in the database. Obviously I want to test these two classes separately. Therefore I wanted to create two test classes which both create the same object.

Comment: @Michael Agreed. Further, some "best practices" quickly fly out the window when testing in particularly more difficult languages to test. DRY is one of them. Having complete, correct tests is _the_ most important thing.

Comment: @david I think I was right then. DAO objects are bad. That's why you're in this situation.

Comment: "At the moment I'm using @Before in each of these classes, which is obviously not a very good solution." Nothing at all obvious about that in the least. Chances are it's probably exactly the right solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for a [`TestRule`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html). To quote the Javadoc:

> A `TestRule` is an alteration in how a test method, or set of test methods, is run and reported. A `TestRule` may add additional checks that cause a test that would otherwise fail to pass, or it may perform necessary setup or cleanup for tests, or it may observe test execution to report it elsewhere. TestRules can do everything that could be done previously with methods annotated with `Before`, `After`, `BeforeClass`, or AfterClass, but they are more powerful, and more easily shared between projects and classes.

It then goes on to list a few types, of which `ExternalResource` is one; but there are others also.

Given that you talk about doing things better than using `@Before` methods, and you're wanting to share between classes, this sounds very much like what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations you've discovered something to improve in your design! This is an excellent result from writing tests.

You say you are using the same test object in multiple tests. I assume your tests are testing different classes. I expect you have uncovered some common behaviour in those different classes that could abstract out into a new class.

Afterwards your test object would test the new class, you could remove it from th other tests, and whatever behaviour remains is different each time. Seems like a good outcome!

Comment: I really like this answer. Don't bodge your tests around a rigid design. Use what you've learned from writing the tests to *inform* the design

Comment: The REST controller is calling the DAO to save the received object. Therefore there isn't really common behavior, one is simply using the other and I wanted to test them both individually. Maybe you're right and this uncovered something I need to improve and I just don't see what it is :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a general class in your test package where you make it available static. It will make it easier to use it in your tests due to static reference. But I'm not sure if it gives a win in test time consumption...

In case of unit test I actually think the win in time with the static object is less because it's all being built up from scratch again each test class, but I can remember somewhere the JVM has it done quicker. (Pls anyone who can confirm or otherwise, tell me as I'm curious about this)

Answer (score 0):

Do not take everything that you read on the interwebz at face value.  Everyone has an opinion and writes about it in a blog, so what.  Inheritance may not be the nicest solution to the problem that you are facing, but it is a solution.  Alternative solutions are not any prettier.  I have tried tests with inheritance on multiple occasions, and they work like a charm.  Just don't go crazy with it, don't create entire inheritance hierarchies, and you will be fine.

If you really want to stay away from inheritance, you might be able to make it work with *Parametrized Tests*. I presume you are using JUnit 4, so you can read about them here: [org.junit.runners Class Parameterized](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html)

Parametrized tests were not exactly invented for the purpose that you want them; they create instances for the cross-product of the test methods of a single class and some test data elements that you supply, but if you use a single data element, and if you use a factory to instantiate the same data element for all of your test classes, then you could possibly achieve the effect that you want.

Personally, I'd still prefer inheritance.

Comment: As Jon Skeet himself says, _Be Pragmatic, Not Dogmatic_.

Comment: yes you're right, I could have gone with the inheritance anyways. Just wanted to see if there is something else..